# Heroku / Devops: Do I need an extra server instance in Asia for my Chinese users?

Tags: heroku, devops

My current user base is all in the US so my current Heroku server is in US-East. However, I am about to add Chinese localizations to my app so I expect a lot of people in China to download my app. I am afraid that my US-East server will be too far and latency will be much higher.

Is it common to deploy multiple instances of my server in different locations? Or can I assume that technology has developed to the point where latency will not be an issue for a CRUD app?

Comment: Curious is heroku servers accessible from China users since there's the great fire wall?

Comment: I think the firewall is a blacklist, not a whitelist. Not 100% sure though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building multi region apps can get complicated very quickly and often introduce new problems on their own. For example, it’s easy to host an Asian app, but what database does it talk to? If it has its own database for speed, how do you sync with your American database? If it will continue to use the American database, you’ll still have latency.

If your application is fairly simple, you’re almost key certainly better off to keep with just a single US based application, and use a CDN such as Cloudflare to cache assets closer to asian clients.